# Removing collaborations from a user's account

Tags: box-api

We have a use case where we would like to remove a user's account in our enterprise. As part of the removal process we want to uncolloborate all of the folders the user owns but is sharing with others. I"m able to remove the user successfully but am stuck trying to uncolloborate all of the folders before removing their account. I've tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work.  This is the code I'm using

```
List<BoxCollaboration> collabs = client.getFoldersManager()
.getFolderCollaborations(entry.getId(),
new BoxDefaultRequestObject());

for (BoxCollaboration collab : collabs) {
    BoxUser collaboratorid = (BoxUser) collab.getAccessibleBy();
    BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject = new BoxDefaultRequestObject(); 
    requestObject.getRequestExtras().addHeader("As-User", userwhoisgettingremived.getId()); 
    client.getCollaborationsManager().deleteCollaboration(collaboratorid , requestObject);
}
```

Anyone have a suggestion of what else I can try.

Thanks in advance
Bill.

Comment: What error is returned?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use "As-User" header as now you are not acting as this user. So the code can be:

```
for (BoxCollaboration collab : collabs) {
    String collaboratorid = collab.getId();
    client.getCollaborationsManager().deleteCollaboration(collaboratorid , null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK  I fixed this by adding the id of the Collaboration instead of the id of the user associated with the collaboration.  so the deleteCollaboration line of code needed to be changed to

client.getCollaborationsManager().deleteCollaboration(collab.getId() , requestObject);